# Prevent objdump from wrapping long lines

Tags: parsing, disassembly, objdump

When using objdump, I often get lines like these:

```
a0df:   c7 05 58 4b 02 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x24b58,0x6400
a0e6:   64 00 00 
...
a2da:   f7 05 6c 4b 02 00 ff    test   DWORD PTR ds:0x24b6c,0xffffffff
a2e1:   ff ff ff
```

What I'd like to get instead is:

```
a0df:   c7 05 58 4b 02 00 00 64 00 00   mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x24b58,0x6400
...
a2da:   f7 05 6c 4b 02 00 ff ff ff ff   test   DWORD PTR ds:0x24b6c,0xffffffff
```

**Is is possible to tell objdump not to wrap those lines?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. I was looking for something named *wrap*, but the parameter that controls this is somewhat disguised as '-w/--wide':

```
   -w
   --wide
       Format some lines for output devices that have more than 80 columns.  
       Also do not truncate symbol names when they are displayed.
```